# Can't connect over https with stunnel - troubleshooting

Tags: linux-networking, https, stunnel

I have stunnel forwarding from HTTP on port 8040 to HTTPS on port 8091.

My `stunnel.conf` file:

```
[henhouse]
accept = 8091
connect = 127.0.0.1:8041
cert = /etc/stunnel/stunnel.pem
```

How I generated said `stunnel.pem` certificate:

```
openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -nodes -out stunnel.pem -keyout stunnel.pem
```

This used to works fine for me. I was connecting to my machine locally. And I can connect remotely at :8040. Unfortunately, when I try to connect remotely to port :8091 over https, I get "The site can't be reached".

Are there any additional settings I should be using here to connect via https? Not clear on how stunnel works/which part of the connection it's responsible for.

My computer is also on a corporate network; can I check to see if a firewall or some other permissions things is preventing me from accessing over https? Not sure what would be preventing this - I can ssh to my computer fine.

Finally, apologies if the question(s) are too generic. Feel free to direct me to some generic HTTPS or linux helpers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Troubleshooting - I went into the office and tried connecting but had the same issue.

Solution - I wasn't forwarding the correct port. ie, my `stunnel.conf` file was forwarding port 8041 but my application was running on port 8040. I switched that over and it works.